# I'm getting an error message on my index numbers and I don't know why

Tags: r, error-handling

[image]

i keep getting the error code, Error in ind1[i]:ind2[i] : NA/NaN argument, i dont know how to fix this and my TA isn't responding

Comment: `ind1` and `ind2` only have 6 elements, but you iterate from 1 through 10. `ind1[7]`, `ind1[8]`, etc. will all return this error that you’re getting

Comment: @mfg3z0 tysm!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read code or data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including the code as plain text.